# Join MS Access data in a column of emails from a filtered sub table into a string for emailing

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that is Company info, in a sub form is a joined table that has company contacts. I would like a button in the parent form that takes all the contacts for that company and creates a string value based on all their email addresses in the email column. This will open an email window for me that has all their emails in the to field.

If this I am new to access and VB but am experienced in DBO and C#, so I can likely understand any answers with not too much explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you need for the first part, but here is the code for the email:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object   

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'Defines Outlook
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) 'Creates an email

With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .Cc = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Body = ""
        .attachments.Add ""
        .Display 'To show email
    .Send 'To send email
End With
```

Comment: I was just going to start a process using the "mailto:" hyperlink prefix for that part, but this is much nicer and is worth a shot for the email part. Still need to join the column of emails to create the `To` field though. Thanks.